# Kattis reversed binary number

Tags: c

i've tried the kattis reversed binary number that have both input and output as integer. example: 13 is 1101 in binary, reversed become 1011 and that is 11.
this is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int a,i=0,temp,arr[10],b,result=0,c;
scanf("%d",&a);
      while(a!=0){
        temp=a%2;
        a=a/2;
        arr[i]=temp;
        i++;
    }
   for(b=i;b>=0;b--){
        c=1;
        result=result + (c*arr[b]);
        c=c*2;
    }
    printf("%d",result);
    return 0;
}
```

if i input 13 then the output is 4099 and i don't know why, can someone help?

Comment: you should have started with b=i-1

Comment: @dineshsaini Please turn that into a (explained) answer, in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `c=c*2;`? It seems like not possibly having an effect.

Answer (score 1):

At this point

```
for(b=i;b>=0;b--){
```

`i` is 4.

So at this point

```
result=result + (c*arr[b]);
```

you access an element of the (luckily large enough) array which you have never written to.
That unpredictable number ends up almost unchanged in your result.

As Dinesh has already mentioned in comments, you should undo the last `i++` to start with the index which has been used last to write to the array. You can do so by

```
for(b=i-1;b>=0;b--){
```

That code will then at least only use initialised values from the array.
It will however end up only counting the set bits, because of another mistake in your code.

I recommend to try your code at this point and attempt to find and fix the problem yourself. There is a hint hidden on this page which will help you.